# Cypher - How to list historical nodes for each current node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm very new in learning Neo4j cypher.

First of all, I have created this sample graph DB through Cypher like this:

```
// Clients
CREATE (Alice:Client {name:'Alice', ip: '1.1.1.1', shipping_address: 'a place', billing_address: 'a place'})
CREATE (Bob:Client {name:'Bob', ip: '1.1.1.2', shipping_address: 'b place', billing_address: 'b place'})
CREATE (Cindy:Client {name:'Cindy', ip: '1.1.1.3', shipping_address: 'c place', billing_address: 'c place'})
CREATE (Diana:Client {name:'Diana', ip: '1.1.1.4', shipping_address: 'd place', billing_address: 'd place'})
CREATE (Emily:Client {name:'Emily', ip: '1.1.1.5', shipping_address: 'e place', billing_address: 'e place'})
CREATE (Fiona:Client {name:'Fiona', ip: '1.1.1.6', shipping_address: 'f place', billing_address: 'f place'})

// Products
CREATE (prod1:Product {name: 'strawberry ice-cream', category: 'ice-cream', price: 6.9, unit: 'box'})
CREATE (prod2:Product {name: 'mint ice-cream', category: 'ice-cream', price: 6.9, unit: 'box'})
CREATE (prod3:Product {name: 'mango ice-cream', category: 'ice-cream', price: 6.9, unit: 'box'})
CREATE (prod4:Product {name: 'cheesecake ice-cream', category: 'ice-cream', price: 7.9, unit: 'box'})
CREATE (prod5:Product {name: 'orange', category: 'furit', unit: 'lb', price: 2.6, unit: 'box'})
CREATE (prod6:Product {name: 'dragon fruit', category: 'furit', unit: 'lb', price: 4.8, unit: 'box'})
CREATE (prod7:Product {name: 'kiwi', category: 'furit', unit: 'lb', price: 5.3, unit: 'box'})
CREATE (prod8:Product {name: 'cherry', category: 'furit', unit: 'lb', price: 4.8, unit: 'box'})
CREATE (prod9:Product {name: 'strawberry', category: 'furit', unit: 'lb', price: 3.9, unit: 'box'})

// Orders
CREATE (d1:Order {id:'d1', name:'d1', deliverdate:'20190410', status:'delivered'})
CREATE (d2:Order {id:'d2', name:'d2', deliverdate:'20130708', status:'delivered'})
CREATE (d3:Order {id:'d3', name:'d3', deliverdate:'20021201', status:'delivered'})
CREATE (d4:Order {id:'d4', name:'d4', deliverdate:'20040612', status:'delivered'})
CREATE (d5:Order {id:'d5', name:'d5', deliverdate:'20110801', status:'delivered'})
CREATE (d6:Order {id:'d6', name:'d6',deliverdate:'20171212', status:'delivered'})

// Link Clients, Orders and ProductsCREATE
CREATE
    (Alice)-[:PLACED]->(d1)-[:CONTAINS {quantity:1}]->(prod1),
    (d1)-[:CONTAINS {quantity:2}]->(prod2),
    (Bob)-[:PLACED]->(d2)-[:CONTAINS {quantity:2}]->(prod1),
    (d2)-[:CONTAINS {quantity:6}]->(prod7),
    (Cindy)-[:PLACED]->(d3)-[:CONTAINS {quantity:1}]->(prod9),
    (Alice)-[:PLACED]->(d4)-[:CONTAINS {quantity:100}]->(prod4),
    (Alice)-[:PLACED]->(d5)-[:CONTAINS {quantity:10}]->(prod8),
    (Alice)-[:PLACED]->(d6)-[:CONTAINS {quantity:1}]->(prod7)
```

Here's the list of orders from Alice:
[image]

**The output I hope to get is**, for each row, get the list of orders that happened before current order. For example:

```
c.name  o.id  historical_orders
"Alice"  "d4"       
"Alice"  "d5"      ["d4"]
"Alice"  "d6"      ["d4", "d5"]
"Alice"  "d1"      ["d4", "d5", "d1"]
```

Is there anyway in Cypher to do this?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far to get the list of orders you want? Also, include the query to get the list of orders from Alice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
MATCH (c:Client {name:'Alice'})-[:PLACED]->(o)
WITH c, o ORDER BY o.deliverdate
WITH c.name AS name, COLLECT(o) AS os
UNWIND [i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(os)-1) |
  {name: name, id: os[i].id, history: [x IN os[0..i] | x.id]}] AS result
RETURN result
```

produces this result:

```
╒═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"result"                                             │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"Alice","id":"d4","history":[]}              │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Alice","id":"d5","history":["d4"]}          │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Alice","id":"d6","history":["d4","d5"]}     │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Alice","id":"d1","history":["d4","d5","d6"]}│
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if we want the results to be returned as a table, just a minor change in return clause:

```
MATCH (c:Client {name:'Alice'})-[:PLACED]->(o)
WITH c, o ORDER BY o.deliverdate
WITH c.name AS name, COLLECT(o) AS os
UNWIND [i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(os)-1) |
  {name: name, id: os[i].id, history: [x IN os[0..i] | x.id]}] AS result
RETURN result.name, result.id as order_id, result.history;
```